# “npm config set prefix” fails on user owned directory in macOS Mojave

Tags: macos, node.js, npm

I am installing node on a clean macOS Mojave box using Homebrew. I am trying to set npm install directory in a user owned dir; the dir `tools` already exists and is owned by the user:

```
npm config set prefix '/Users/giorgio/tools/npm_global'
```

And that fails with this message. Does anyone know what is going on?

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/tools'
TypeError: Cannot read property 'loaded' of undefined
    at exit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:98:27)
    at errorHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:216:3)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:78:20
    at cb (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:225:22)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:263:24
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:83:7
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:82:13
    at f (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/once/once.js:25:25)
    at afterExtras (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:173:20)
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:98
  var doExit = npm.config.loaded ? npm.config.get('_exit') : true
                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'loaded' of undefined
    at exit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:98:27)
    at process.errorHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:216:3)
    at process.emit (events.js:197:13)
    at process._fatalException (internal/process/execution.js:123:25)
```

Comment: What is the output of `npm config get prefix`? Also, [look at this](https://gist.github.com/DanHerbert/9520689) as well [as this](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3794).

Comment: @JakeGould Thanks for the links! I have found a solution by manually removing the `.npmrc` file and reissuing the command. It's really weird that `set prefix` would not be able to overwrite its own config file

Comment: Cool you fixed this! But not shocking. The problem I have had with package managers for tons of languages is they really don’t catch every case. They try to make the command line “easy” and they mostly succeed. But then a “Gotcha!” comes up and suddenly your coding flow comes to a screeching halt. In general, you always should look towards doing a “Tabula rasa.” recreation of your development setup for cases just like this. It‘s the nuclear option but often the only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution quite randomly. Seems like the first time I tried to `set prefix` I did use a wrong path string. I had to manually remove the `.npmrc` file and retry the `set prefix` command to make it work.

I would really have expected `set prefix` to be able to modify the npn config files created by itself though.

Comment: Hi I'm having the same issue where do you find .npmrc

Comment: never mind found it sudo rm /Users/[username]/.npmrc